# Adding post limit on certain page using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently using the following code in a new page template from Wordpress to add specific category posts to the home page:

```
<?php global $post; // required
$args = array('category' => 3); // include category 3
$custom_posts = get_posts($args);
foreach($custom_posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);

// put here what you want to appear for each post like:
//the title:

the_title('<h3 class="no-margin">', '</h3>');

// an excerpt:
the_excerpt();

//and so on...    

endforeach;
?>
```

All work fine however I need to limit the amount of posts showing, they already appear on the main news page, I just need to show the latest 2 or 3 on home page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php global $post; // required
$args = array('category' => 3, 'numberposts' => 5); // include category 3 and limit to 5 posts
$custom_posts = get_posts($args);
foreach($custom_posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);

// put here what you want to appear for each post like:
//the title:

the_title('<h3 class="no-margin">', '</h3>');

// an excerpt:
the_excerpt();

//and so on...    

endforeach;
?>
```